# Repeated Data Reading/Loading from Firebase Database in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to fetch user's names from firebase database and display them on the home screen. Unfortunately, whenever I hot reload the app or just switch between the bottom navigation bar items, the data items duplicates. The more I tap or reload, the more copies are created. Please help to find my mistake.

The code is as following;

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:practice/Get_User_Data/get_user_name.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePage();
}

int currentindex = 0;

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  List<String> docIDs = [];

  Future getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .orderBy('First Name')
        .get()
        .then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
              print(document.reference);
              docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            },
          ),
        );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedindex = 0;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              setState(() {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return const LoginPage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          )
        ],
        title: Text(user.email!),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 5.0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[200],
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getDocId(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: docIDs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          child: ListTile(
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            selectedColor: Colors.yellow,
                            title: GetUserName(documentId: docIDs[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: GNav(
            tabBackgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            gap: 10.0,
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
            hoverColor: Colors.yellow,
            activeColor: Colors.red,
            iconSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            tabs: const [
              GButton(
                icon: Icons.chat_bubble_rounded,
                text: 'Chats',
              ),
              GButton(
                icon: Icons.search_rounded,
                text: 'Search',
              ),
              GButton(
                icon: Icons.settings,
                text: 'Settings',
              ),
            ],
            selectedIndex: selectedindex,
            onTabChange: (index) {
              setState(
                () {
                  selectedindex = index;
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue due to the way you are calling the getDocId() function inside the FutureBuilder. The getDocId() function adds document IDs to the docIDs list, and you are calling this function multiple times within the ListView.builder. To solve this issue, you should call the getDocId() function only once and outside the FutureBuilder.

```
    return Scaffold(
      // provide your initial code here
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: docIDs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        selectedColor: Colors.yellow,
                        title: GetUserName(documentId: docIDs[index]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),


// provide the necessary code here


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But this did not work for me.